# Accessing a wireless router on a different subnet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, subnet

Okay, I'll try to describe how this network is set up. I didn't do it personally, but it has been described to me. Firstly, we get our internet from a 3G wireless USB card from ATT. This means that our internet goes directly into the desktop computer sitting in our living room (running Windows 7). This desktop is then connected to a netgear router, which routes all the traffic to various devices. The router does not function as a DHCP server. All gateways lead back to the Windows box. The router simply routes traffic. Apparently, the router was (somehow) put onto a different subnet than the rest of the system. This was done, because it was apparently trying to take things over (as many routers assume they need to handle DHCP, etc.). I need to access the routers settings, yet I can't get to the configuration page.

To be honest, I don't have much experience with networking. I'm pretty good with computers (I do a lot of programming), but networks get a little fuzzy with me... I understand the basic idea of a subnet, but I can't figure out how to access it. Once I'm connected to the subnet, I should, theoretically, be able to access the router through the host name "routerlogin.net", according to my router documentation.

I'm not sure of the subnet that was used, although I'm fairly certain it would be a somewhat standard one, and I've found the few standard private subnets, so after I know how to connect to a different subnet, I will try and find exactly which one it is... :/ Haha

I'm running Kubuntu 11.10, and am connect, through ethernet to the router itself. I can use the main desktop Windows 7 box, if need be, but I would rather not use Windows ;)

Comment: So do you know the address of the router?  If so just set a static address on your box to the same subnet, and plug in to a spare port on the router.  From there you should be able to log in to the router and configure it.

Comment: No, I don't. :/ It was written down, and the owner lost it. Resetting would be a large pain. So, having an address within the subnet of the router is all I need? Okay, that's not hard. Well, it's going to be a pain finding the router (Hopefully, I'll get lucky with an ip scanner...), but I'll deal with it. If you'd like to put that in the form of an answer, I'd accept it. I'm just trying to figure out how to access another subnet, and it seems that this answers my question! Haha

Comment: What is the make/model of the router?  I'd like to know it works before saving it as an answer :)

Comment: It's a Netgear WGR614v9. That makes sense. I completely understand! :D

Comment: So by default it looks like the IP would be set to either 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.1.  If you're lucky these didn't change when the network was set up and you can just static your PC to 192.168.x.2 for example.  What is the active network set to?

Comment: If by "active network" you mean the set of addresses that are currently being used, it is 192.168.0.0-255. Our desktop machine is 192.168.0.1, so if the router was still 192.168.1.1, would I just need to set my static IP address to 192.168.1.2, and try it?

Comment: Couldn't think of a good way to describe it but yes, that is correct.

Comment: Okay, well that didn't work. :/ I guess I'm going to have to resort to resetting the router, unless anymore smart people come along... Haha :P